# Is it safe to manually delete the contents of the .Trash-1000 folder on my SDCard?

Tags: sd-card, file-system

Can anyone please provide an explanation (or a good resource) of how the folder `/mnt/sdcard/.Trash-1000` functions and whether or not it was safe to manually delete its contents?  Based on the name and the way it seemingly acts it would be logical to assume that it's a garbage folder, but you know what happens when you assume...

In case it matters I'm running CyanogenMod 6.2.1 (based on Android 2.2.1) on my Motorola Droid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.Trash-1000` is a metafolder like Windows's Recycle Bin, normally created by Ubuntu (and perhaps other Linux variants).  Have you deleted anything on your SD card from your PC?  That would explain it.  You can safely delete it.  See also: https://superuser.com/questions/169980/what-is-trash-and-trash-1000

Comment: I dunno for sure, but I am running Ubuntu at home and I have browsed my SDCard from my computer in the past, so it stands to reason that you've nailed down where it came from.  I had to use the Terminal Emulator to run `cd /mnt/sdcard` then `su` then `rm -fr .Trash-1000`.  Ubuntu mounted the SDCard as a read-only file system so I couldn't run `rm` from the terminal on my computer.