# could someone please post a screenshot of the default file structure of the sd card for Android 2.3.5? I

Tags: sd-card, file-system, file-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which files/folders on my SDCard are unsafe to delete manually?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7351/which-files-folders-on-my-sdcard-are-unsafe-to-delete-manually)

I have searched the internet for what I felt would be a simple question.  I have had my Evo for almost 18 months, and I know I will be resetting it soon, probably rooting it also.  But need to clean up the SD card.  Many strange looking folders that were created by apps that were deleted long ago.  If I knew what was supposed to be there by default, then I would have a better chance to figure out what is there that doesn't have to be.

Comment: Thanks for searching first, but I believe the dupe should answer your question :)

Comment: Wow thats the second question that was closed without an answer.  Was looking for the entire file tree so I could pick out what I had that wasn't supposed to be there.  Would you please post the answer because the referred question didn't answer it.

Comment: The SD card starts out empty, there isn't a default file structure.  Any directory listing would be entirely dependent on what someone had done with their device.